# Sorting error for average score

Tags: python, sorting, average

```
viewclass= input("choose a class number and either alphabetically, average or highest?")#type in what you want to select 




if viewclass=='1 average':#variable inputted
    with open("1.txt") as f:#open text file
        d = {}

    for line in f:
        column = line.split(":")#split name and score
        names = column[0]#names in column
        scores = int(column[1].strip())

        count = 0
        while count < 3:
            d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)#name and scores added to end of list
            count = count + 1 
    for names, v in sorted(d.items()):#sorted
        average = (sum(v)/len(v))
        print(names,average)#average score printed
    averages=[]
    averages.append(average)    


elif viewclass=='2 average':
    with open("2.txt") as f:
        d = {}

    for line in f:
        column = line.split(":")
        names = column[0]
        scores = int(column[1].strip())

        count = 0
        while count < 3:
            d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)
            count = count + 1
    for names, v in sorted(d.items()):
        average = (sum(v)/len(v))
        print(names,average)
    averages=[]
    averages.append(average)  

elif viewclass=='3 average':
    with open("3.txt") as f:
        d = {}

    for line in f:
        column = line.split(":")
        names = column[0]
        scores = int(column[1].strip())

        count = 0
        while count < 3:
            d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)
            count = count + 1
    for names, v in sorted(d.items()):
        average = (sum(v)/len(v))
        print(names,average)
    averages=[]
    averages.append(average)
```

my other code works but when for this when I run it signal file it works but when I select it I get this error

```
choose a class number and either alphabetically, average or highest?1 average
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users//Documents/New folder (2)/14343 - Copy.py", line 10, in <module>
    for line in f:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("3.txt") as f:
    d = {}
```

You are finishing the with function by creating the dictionary

When with is finished the file opened are `closed`

It should be like the following

```
with open("2.txt") as f:
    d = {}

    for line in f:
        column = line.split(":")
        names = column[0]
        scores = int(column[1].strip())

        count = 0
        while count < 3:
            d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)
            count = count + 1
```

`with` is know as `context manager` they open the file when the function starts and closes the file when their function finishes

**You have done the same error many times**

The actual  error is suggesting that you are reading content of a closed file object